# Load Angular Template when tab is active

Tags: angularjs, optimization, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm new to Angular, so just learning the specifics. I'm building a data dashboard and linking to my own REST interface. Currently my app is incredibly slow.

Basically what I have is a few different "views" that load as tab-content.

I'm using angular Routes to map view templates to the content of each tab when it's clicked. I've tried different other structures - controllers & directives, but I *think* Routes are the most efficient.

The content of each tab is grabbing a bunch of data and populating it into a table under each tab. i.e. each table has different data that only needs to be accessed when the tab is active/ clicked.

I'm concerned that in my current set up, all data (for every table) is being called when the initial page is loaded thus slowing down initial app load significantly. Am I right in thinking this?

How can I optimise my current set up to only load the view/data as it's needed?

index.php

```
<div ng-app="myApp" class="row-fluid">
   // Lods the controller which isn't really being used
   <div class="right-container" ng-controller="MainController">
      // Loads the clickable tabs
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified">
          <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#inventory" >Inventory</a></li>
           <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#orders" >Orders</a></li>
           <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#products" >Products</a></li>
       </ul>
       // Loads the tab content & ng-view for the Angular Routes
       <div class="tab-content">
           <div ng-view></div>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

my app.js file:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function ($routeProvider) { 
  $routeProvider 
    .when('/', { 
      controller: 'MainController', 
      templateUrl: 'js/views/inventory.php' 
    })
    .when('/inventory', { 
      templateUrl: 'js/views/inventory.php' 
    }) 
    .when('/orders', { 
      templateUrl: 'js/views/orders.php' 
    }) 
    .when('/products', { 
      templateUrl: 'js/views/products.php' 
    }) 
    .otherwise({ 
      redirectTo: '/' 
    }); 
});
```

A sample of one of my views - the data is loaded into a boostrap table here directly - each view has different data coming from a separate API, but I think in my current set up (as it is going painfully slow) that all the data is coming down in each of the views when the main page is loaded.

js/views/inventory.php

```
<div id="inventory" class="tab-pane active">
    <table class="col-xs-12 text-center" id="inventoryTable" data-url="http://myrestapi.com/api/v1/inventory">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th data-field ="name">Name</th>
                <th data-field="modifiedTime">Last Modified</th>
                <th data-field="stockCount">Current Stock</th>
                <th data-field="cost">Cost Price</th>
                <th data-field="price">Price</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

if you use different routes, don't think of the tabs as toggle content... just think of the tab html as nav tabs that require no javascript

So you don't need the `data-toggle` for them.

What you will need is a way to set the active class based on route.

For just a few of them you could use `ng-class` and set it active for appropriate path from `$location.path()`